# is there a solar passive water condenser (from humid air) design anywhere?

Tags: water, energy-efficiency, gardening

i've looked around and i found only two related designs:

1. active electric water condenser.
2. solar passive water still (that distill dirty water)

not quite what i was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finely, i've found [this product](http://www.groasis.com/page/uk/principle.php). the closest i came to... although i would like to find a diy design that generates water for adults trees.